# Kendo UI Menu Doesn't work in IE (Touch)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-menu

Kendo UI Menu doesn't work in IE on Tablets running Windows 8 (IE 10 & IE 11). The menu drop down doesn't work. The menu works in Google chrome on the same Windows tablet.

Comment: if you hit F12 in chrome, to show dev tools, do you got some error (red notitication) in bottom right corner?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you posted a code example.

By far the most common problem I have with things not working on IE is with trailing commas in arrays. For example:

```
menuItems=[12,33,44,2,7,];
```

Runs just fine in chrome but IE breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to a newer version of Kendo. They fixed this in their Q2 2013 release 2013.2.918.

[Kendo Link](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/menu/menu-select-event-not-firing-in-ie-11-non-compat-mode.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The latest version from [KendoUIWeb (2013.3.1119)](http://www.kendoui.com/web/whats-new/release-notes/q3-2013-web.aspx) does now also solve this issue.